# Is it possible to place all the Kivy code in a python user function, called from Main?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy for a user interface to a control application.  As such, the UI is subsidiary to the essential functionality.  For modularity/tidyness, I've been trying to place all the Kivy code in a separate source file and to call it as the last step in Main.

However, if I do this, I find that some things don't work properly (for example, creating labels programatically and updating their text by scheduled events).

Is this something which should be possible?
Is there a 'trick' of which I should be aware?

If the detail of my question is not clear, I can put up some test code to illustrate.

Monolithic code, which works as expected:

```
cat test.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

Builder.load_string('''
<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: Box1
        size: root.size
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Change text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
''')

class YourWidget(Screen):
    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        label = Label(
                      id= 'label1',
                      text = self.random_number
                     )
        self.ids.Box1.add_widget(label)
        self.random_number = 'ini'
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_text,1)

    def change_text(self, *largs):
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))


class updatetestapp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(YourWidget(name='d_analogs'))

        return YourWidget()

if (True):
    updatetestapp().run()
```

If I then attempt to modularise my code, placing all the Kivy processing in a user function,everything works except the display of the ransom number variable. The variable persists through successive callbacks, as shown by calls to print, but it simply doesn't display.  I'm guessing that this is something to do with the scope or context of the variable - Kivy isn't displaying the same variable which is being updated in the callback.

```
cat Main.py
#from mytest import mytest
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

from display import *

def main():

    Display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
cat display.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

Builder.load_string('''
<YourWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: Box1
        size: root.size
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Change text"
            on_release: root.change_text()
''')

class YourWidget(Screen):
    random_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(YourWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        label = Label(
                      id= 'label1',
                      text = self.random_number
                     )
        self.ids.Box1.add_widget(label)
        self.random_number = 'ini'
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_text,1)

    def change_text(self, *largs):
        self.random_number = str(random.randint(1, 100))


class test(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(YourWidget(name='d_analogs'))

        return YourWidget()

def Display():
    test().run()
```

Comment: A good place to call something like `Builder.load_flle()` or `Builder.load_string()` is in the `build()` method of the `App`, before any widgets are created. Or just use a correctly named `kv` file and let `Kivy` load it.

Comment: There is no fundamental issue with running python code before the Kivy app. If you believe you're having a problem with that, please post a minimal runnable example.

Comment: @inclement  Thanks for your interest in my issue - I have updated my original post to add sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any code that would change the text of your Label. Although you update `self.random_number`, you don't update the Label's text property, therefore you don't see any change.

Comment: thanks for your continued interest and forbearance!  Unfortunately, I'm not much enlightened by your response.  The first piece of code I posted doesn't, as far as I can see, do anything different to the second example, yet that first one updates the label text as I expect.  Anyway, what should I be doing to 'update the Label's text property'?

Comment: Your first example also doesn't work. Are you sure it matches your code?

Comment: The first example definitely works for me. To be sure, I simply copied the code from above, saved it and ran it.  The label text updates perfectly well every second. Now I'm more confused than ever!  In case it matters, I'm running Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi, Python 3.7.```[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-04-11_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-11c9fe6, 20180824
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (default, Aug  6 2018, 18:15:19) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180531]
```

Comment: For an oldie who started programming in FORTRAN IV, hand-punching card decks, back in 1970, teaching myself Python, and then throwing Kivy into the mix, is taxing my brain!

Comment: Anyway, can you suggest what is the obvious, or best, method to 'update the Label's text property'?

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by the Label's text property? And do you see why this is a problem, the fact that you never give it any value?

Comment: You can make it "work" by adding something like `self.ids.Box1.children[0].text = self.random_numbe` in the `change_text` method, but this isn't a good solution. More important is to understand why you need to do that, and find a way to fit it in better. You may find [these resources](http://inclem.net/) useful.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to your resources. I will work through your text tutorials (being an oldie, I cope better with text than video!).  Even the first tutorial has given me a better insight/understanding of what is going on.